# What's the Haar measure of non semi-simple Lie group?

Tags: measure-theory, differential-geometry, lie-groups

For semi-simple Lie group, there exist a bi-invariant non-degenerated metric $g$ on Lie group and the metric in the Tangent space of indentiy is Killing form. Certainly for manifold with non-degenerated metric, we can construct the Haar measure $\sqrt{|g|}dx^1\wedge\cdots\wedge dx^n$.

My question is how to construct the Haar measure in a non-semisimple Lie group? Because the bi-invariant metric in these Lie group is degenerate.

Comment: For general groups, the left-invariant and right-invariant Haar measures need not coincide.

Comment: @GEdgar Are there some literatures that talks about these content? Thanks

Comment: There is a construction in chapter 10 in *Structure and Geometry of Lie Groups$ by Hilgert and Neeb. For a construction for general locally compact groups, see e.g. here: https://people.math.ethz.ch/~lang/HaarIntegral.pdf. But there are many other places as well.

Comment: The Killing form in a semisimple group may well be non-positive definite.

Answer (score 2):

Haar measure by definition is only left invariant, and it is not bi-invariant in general (this is measured by the so-called modular function). Hence you can simply choose a non-zero element in $\Lambda^n\mathfrak g^*$, where $\mathfrak g$ is the Lie algebra of $G$ and $n$ is its dimension. This gives rise to a left invariant form of top degree on $G$, which then induces the Haar measure. As inidcated in the comment by @Cronus, there is a general constuction for locally compact topological groups, but this is significantly more complicated.

Comment: The [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1909982/whats-the-haar-measure-of-non-semi-simple-lie-group#comment3922693_1909982) by @Cronus.